# How to fix Expo push notifications error: "Couldn't get GCM token for device"?

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a new Expo project and I tried to get push notifications token but it fails. I got an error: "[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Couldn't get GCM token for device]". How I can fix this? Thanks!
My device: Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017), android 8.0.0

I read about this and it should work with "expo start", but for me this don't work. "expo start" is default in package.json .

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

App.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.registerForPushNotifications();
}

registerForPushNotifications = async () => {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
        Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
    );
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted'){
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {return;}
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    console.log("token: ",token);
};
```

Comment: The problem was resolved after I restarted my computer and device. Maybe it was a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else facing this problem, try the following (not in order):

- Run your app using "expo start". Install the expo-cli if you have not already done so.
- Clear your apps cache
- Log in to expo on your cli using "expo login"

These steps did it for me. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You'll need an account on the [Expo.io](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjj4vDLj-XlAhVznVwKHeowBQYQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fexpo.io%2Fsignup&usg=AOvVaw09I4pefKHcIRf9acgve0Nq).

Then you'll have to enter the following command in the Terminal on which you are interacting with the Expo.

```
expo login
```

It will ask you to enter the username, password of your expo account. You can check the image below, to see how it looks in the Visual Studio Code.

[image]

For details, check the [Github answer](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2073)